# What technique(s) should be used to secure funds in my wallet(s)?

Tags: security, monero-wallet-cli, cold-storage, hot-wallet

So I know that there might not be a straight forward answer besides having a cold and hot wallet available that you can access with your own daemon and simplewallet. But I feel like there might be more ways/techniques that some of you might do  to better secure your funds.

So how many cold and hot wallets do you have and how should you distribute your funds amongst them, or do you? Do you give the wallets really obscure names on simple wallet? Super long and random passwords? Or is none of these super paranoid tactics really worth it for monero?

Answer (score 4):

The first line of defense: use a secure operating system. This means no Windows, no running random binaries (except below), and keeping patches up to date. If you know how to use them, use VMs, and do all risky stuff on VMs, not the host.

When you've done that, backup your wallet/seed, use a complex password for your keys file.

Comment: I see where your coming from, but my question is more along the lines of, I guess, "limiting your losses" with hot wallets and if you should store your monero on more than one hot/cold wallet.

Comment: One size doesn't fit all. :) Use 1 cold wallet, or 1 cold and 1 "ice cold", etc etc.